# How to hide these lines so i can see only grass texture?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I cant hide or delete this lines on grass so it is looking awful[image: enter image descrip]

Answer (score 1):

Deselect the **Wireframe** option in object properties panel perhaps?

[image]

Also in viewport overlay option:

[image: s]

Comment: Nope,i did this grass by this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GAm-7_3N6g but this lines just dissapear when he is not сlicking on grass in video

Comment: @Капибара Need more information in your problem. Hard to tell with your context.